# knockoutjs with custom jQuery validation rules

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate

How can i add custom jquery validation rules against the fields generated from knockoutjs's template items?

In this modified example of 'Editable grid' (http://jsfiddle.net/cEy2X/), I have changed the Price field to a Date field. I would like to add custom jQuery validation rules on the date fields. I know jQuery Validation has a built-in 'date' for that, but it's just a dumb javascript date format check.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your the part where it validates the price for a number with the following

```
<td><input class='required date' data-bind='value: price, uniqueName: true' /></td>
```

change number to date and it does validates the date for you. if that what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/cEy2X/15/

Comment: I want to avoid the built-in 'date' validation since it's not a good validation based on javascript.